# Re-usable component with shared Model angular 4

Tags: angular

I'm beginning in Angular 4 and I wan't to make re-usable components.
Here is my app structure :

```
app:
    application-list:
        application.ts
        application-list.component.ts
        application-list.component.html
        application-list.component.css
        application-list-component.spec.ts

     user-list:
        user.ts
        user-list.component.ts
        user-list.component.html
        user-list.component.css
        user-most.component.spec.ts
```

I wan't to make application-list re-usable but this component depends on the user.ts model.

I read that putting the user.ts class inside a service isn't a good practice.
I also read that I can use a shared folder on the app's root but my component will be not re-usable as I wan't.

Or maybe I just can't and I must make a generic Service which returns a dictionary used in application-list.component.ts ?

Do you have any idea to do that properly?

Comment: What is the `model`? Is it just a class? In the list component you can just do `import { User } from '../user-list/user'`

Comment: Hello, 

it is just a class.
If i use     import { User } from '../user-list/user'  I'm dependent on the user-list module.
I don't wan't that.

Comment: Why don't you want that? What do you mean it's dependent on the module?

Comment: Because I wan't that my application-list doesn't depends on this unique User model and I wan't that anyone who needs to use the application-list can use it with its own user.ts model without rewriting the import.

That's why I thought to put the class inside the service which expose the datas to the components but it's a bad practice

Comment: If your application list was built to be used in a generic way why does it need the User model at all?

Comment: Because I think that reading a class is easier than a dictionary (according to me)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, if you want to make your component reusable, you must put him in a dedicated module or you can only use it in one module since you cannot declare a component several times.

If you're not going to use `application-list` in another application, it's not a bad practive to share your models between standalone components.

Otherwise since `user.ts` is just an interface (a list of fields), you could duplicate it. Especially since it's possible that your two components are not interessted by the same fields. In the end these are just javascript objects. They can be casted at will.

Comment: Duplicate code is not a good option to me, if I wan't to modify one class I have to modify the other.

Comment: It's usual to have duplicated models. There is no logic. Especially since it's possible that your two components are not interessted by the same fields. Otherwise `user.ts` is obligatorily a shared dependency. If you don't use your component in several applications, the shared dependency is the best option.